# UnPublish is failing in Committing Deployment Phase

Tags: 2011

I am trying to unpublish a js file, but it is failing. Error is below:

> Committing Deployment Failed
>   Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-26752-66560, com/tridion/storage/filesystem/componentpresentationmeta/XMLComponentPresentationMetaReader, com/tridion/storage/filesystem/componentpresentationmeta/XMLComponentPresentationMetaReader, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-26752-66560, com/tridion/storage/filesystem/componentpresentationmeta/XMLComponentPresentationMetaReader, com/tridion/storage/filesystem/componentpresentationmeta/XMLComponentPresentationMetaReader

When I am publishing the same js file, it is publishing successfully. What can be the reason?
Below is the storage Conf:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration Version="6.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
    <Global>
        <ObjectCache Enabled="false">
            <Policy Type="LRU" Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy">
                <Param Name="MemSize" Value="16mb"/>
            </Policy>
            <Features>
                <Feature Type="DependencyTracker" Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker"/>
            </Features>
        </ObjectCache>
        <Storages>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="/var/content/portal_other/DefaultData" />
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="propertiesFile" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="/var/portal_ro/config/app_conf" />
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="assetsMobile" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="/var/portal_ro/htdocs/webapps/ROOT/assets/mobile" />
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="assetsWeb" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="/var/portal_ro/htdocs/webapps/ROOT/assets/web" />
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="assetsFont" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="/var/portal_ro/htdocs/webapps/ROOT/assets" />
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="ClientWenEN" defaultFilesystem="false">
                <Root Path="/var/portal_ro/htdocs/webapps/ROOT/web/en" />
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="ClientMobileEN" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="/var/portal_ro/htdocs/webapps/ROOT/mobile/en" />
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="ClientWebES" defaultFilesystem="false">
                <Root Path="/var/portal_ro/htdocs/webapps/ROOT/web/es" />
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="ClientMobileES" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="/var/portal_ro/htdocs/webapps/ROOT/mobile/es" />
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="xmlStorageEN" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="/var/portal_ro/config/app_conf/xmlstorage/content/en" />
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="xmlStorageES" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="/var/portal_ro/config/app_conf/xmlstorage/content/es" />
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="sysConfig" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="/var/portal_ro/config/app_conf" />
            </Storage>
        </Storages>
    </Global>
    <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultFile" cached="false">
        <Publication Id="12" defaultStorageId="defaultFile" cached="false">
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".svg" storageId="assetsFont" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".eot" storageId="assetsFont" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".js" storageId="assetsFont" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".css" storageId="assetsFont" cached="false"/>
        </Publication>
        <Publication Id="18" defaultStorageId="defaultFile" cached="false">
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".pdf" storageId="assetsWeb" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".doc" storageId="assetsWeb" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".jpg" storageId="assetsWeb" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".png" storageId="assetsWeb" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".bmp" storageId="assetsWeb" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".jpeg" storageId="assetsWeb" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".ico" storageId="assetsWeb" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".gif" storageId="assetsWeb" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".js" storageId="assetsWeb" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".css" storageId="assetsWeb" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".htc" storageId="assetsWeb" cached="false"/>
            <!--For Config XML n properties-->
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".properties" storageId="sysConfig" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="sysConfig" cached="false"/>
            <!--For Audio Files-->
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".wav" storageId="assetsWeb" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".mp3" storageId="assetsFont" cached="false"/>
        </Publication>
        <Publication Id="19" defaultStorageId="defaultFile" cached="false">
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".pdf" storageId="assetsMobile" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".doc" storageId="assetsMobile" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".jpg" storageId="assetsMobile" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".png" storageId="assetsMobile" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".bmp" storageId="assetsMobile" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".jpeg" storageId="assetsMobile" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".ico" storageId="assetsMobile" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".gif" storageId="assetsMobile" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".js" storageId="assetsMobile" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".css" storageId="assetsMobile" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".htc" storageId="assetsMobile" cached="false"/>
        </Publication>
        <Publication Id="22" defaultStorageId="defaultFile" cached="false">
            <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="ClientWenEN"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="ClientWenEN" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="xmlStorageEN" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".properties" storageId="propertiesFile" cached="false"/>
            <!--For Config XML n properties-->
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".properties" storageId="sysConfig" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="sysConfig" cached="false"/>
        </Publication>
        <Publication Id="23" defaultStorageId="defaultFile" cached="false">
            <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="ClientMobileEN"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="ClientMobileEN" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="xmlStorageEN" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".properties" storageId="propertiesFile" cached="false"/>
        </Publication>
        <Publication Id="26" defaultStorageId="defaultFile" cached="false">
            <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="ClientWebES"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="ClientWebES" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="xmlStorageES" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".properties" storageId="propertiesFile" cached="false"/>
        </Publication>
        <Publication Id="27" defaultStorageId="defaultFile" cached="false">
            <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="ClientMobileES"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="ClientMobileES" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="xmlStorageES" cached="false"/>
            <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".properties" storageId="propertiesFile" cached="false"/>
        </Publication>
    </ItemTypes>
    <License Location="/var/content/portal_other/Tridion/Tridion_licenses/cd_licenses.xml"/>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Could you please share the cd_storage configuration of the publisher.

Comment: I have updated in my question.

Comment: What happens if you create a new JS file, publish it and then unpublish it?  If it unpublishes correctly then it would indicate a problem with this specific Binary (or Metadata), rather than the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not much help, but here's a few pointers that may help:

- The error is linked to failing to read the (file system) metadata for that JS file
- Have you tried looking at the metadata for the file as stored in your file system, and checked for any obvious issues with it (file paths, tcm IDs, etc)?
- You say that publishing works, can you check what (if any thing) changes in the metadata for that file?

Due to the classes used I can only assume you're publishing the JS as a DCP. Might be worth checking the behavior of this template with other files - does it also fail to unpublish other files, or only this one JS file?

BTW, I would advise you to read chapter 4.3.5 of the [SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 Deprecation Guide](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/SDL%20Tridion%202011%20SP1%20Deprecation%20Guide_tcm89-20342.pdf) - File system metadata has been deprecated and may not work on a future release (still does on 2013).